# Json.NET in Unity throwing 'The type or namespace `Newtonsoft` could not be found'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I used nuget to install Json.NET into my Unity project but the issue is when I launch it throws
`The type or namespace 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference`
Yet it is in my references and I have `using Newtonsoft.Json;`
I have looked at other questions but I could not an answer which worked. I am using Unity 5 and the latest version of Json.NET

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**1**.In Unity, place the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` file into the `Assets/Plugins` folder

**2**.In Visual Studio, highlight `Analyzers` in the in `Solution Explorer` window.

**3**.Go to `Project`**->** `Add Reference` and choose your project directory followed by `Assets/Plugin`. That's it.

**Optional**:

In Unity 5.3, Unity added [native support](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) of `Json` serialization. You can simply use that to convert to `Json` and back to `class`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I feel stupid for not trying this to be fair. Thanks again.

Comment: I needed make these changes for each project in my sln (jumped to error, select Analyzers for the project containing that file, add reference, jump to next error) and to restart Unity to make it accept my changes.

Comment: @idbrii Not supposed to happen. Note that if you want to use Newtonsoft, you have to use the Unity forked Unity version. You can get that [here](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D)

Comment: @Programmer: Not sure the fork is still necessary? Newtonsoft 11 loads and builds/parses json without errors in Unity 5.6 (targetting desktop).

Comment: @idbrii In the past, there used to be some errors on some platforms like iOS. Also, it requires .NET 4.5. I don't think this has changed.

Comment: 11.0.2 comes with dlls for .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5.

Comment: @Programmer native JSON serialization is crippled compared to newtonsoft. Try serializing and deserializing a List<ComplexType> :/

Answer (score 11):

Go to:

```
Window -> Package Manager
```

Click on the plus button

```
Add Package from GIT URL > com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: great, thanks tested and worked!

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer will work, and only requires step 1 in current versions of Unity. However, there is a cleaner solution:

1. Open the `Packages` folder in your system's file browser
2. edit `manifest.json`
3. In the dependencies section, add this line:

   "com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json": "2.0.0"
4. (optional) go to the Package Manager window and update to the current version

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Assets/JsonDotNet/Assemblies/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json` then in Inspector check proper platform (`iOS`, `Android` or `Lumin`) checkbox in General, select proper platform in `Platform Settings` and hit `Apply`.